# how to show select2 after select2 the data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i just want to choose data again after select2 with select2, but not showing the data

```
loadUser();

       function loadUser() {
           $('#wg').empty();
           $.ajax({
               url: "<?php echo site_url('administrator/admin/getWg'); ?>",
               type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'JSON',
           }).done(function(data) {
               console.log('data: ', data);

               $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                   $('#wg').append($('<option>', {
                       value: item.workgroup,
                       text: item.workgroup
                   }));
               });
           });

           $('#wg').change(function() {
               wg = $(this).val(),
                   $.ajax({
                       url: '<?php echo site_url("administrator/admin/getWg2"); ?>/' + wg,
                       dataType: 'JSON',
                       type: 'GET',
                   }).done(function(data) {
                       console.log('use: ', data);
                       $('#name').val(data.name);
                   });
           });
       }
```

but, if i use the input data without the select2 the data showing but only the first array, how to showing the all data ?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                           <label for="wg">Workgroup</label>
                           <select class="form-control select2" id="wg" name="wg"></select>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <label for="name">Name</label>
                           <input class="form-control select2" id="name" name="name">
                           
                       </div>
```

just how to use the select2 twice.

Comment: Hi, please elaborate more .

Comment: you will need to initialize the select2 two times and also give different data id